# Problem with accuracy of AD633 multiplier

Tags: multiplier, precision, tolerance

I have 3pcs of AD633 chips, and the accuracy should be ±1% (typical), ±2% (max) according to datasheet.

I wired it like this:

[image]

I tried several  input voltages, but it seems, that output is still way out of tolerance.
For example:

```
IN1=7.008V
IN2=2.003V
OUT=1.4537V
```

Output should be precisely 1.4037V. But it's 3.5% out.
All 3 my chips are out of tolerance (up to 5%).

I don't know if there is problem in my circuit?
Or problem is that all of those chips are out of tolerance? (bought from China)

Comment: Tie the inputs together and tell us the output when input is 0 V, 1 V, 2 V, 3 V, etc.

Comment: What are you using to measure these voltages?

Comment: You may have to separately account for DC offsets (what does it do when one input is exactly 0V) etc - when that's done, you may find it is within spec. Or not...

Comment: I started to do measurements suggested by transistor. Thanks to that, I noticed some shimmering on voltmeter's bargraph. I did not notice that before. So I found out that quality of used ±12V power source is the culprit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I made very basic error. Problem was in quality of ±12V power source.
After I added some capacitors, precision of those multipliers improved dramatically.
[image]

Precision is within 1% now.

```
IN1=7.004V
IN2=2.0046V
OUT=1.4082V
```

So, now it is out by 0.3%. That is better :)

Comment: Good work. Many are tempted to leave out the decoupling capacitors recommended by the datasheets. The question to ask is "what do these people know that the manufacturers don't"! You have now learned that lesson! Thanks for letting us know.

Comment: I did not care about decoupling capacitors because datasheet says: "multiplier accuracy is essentially supply insensitive".